# ListView with ContextMenu option

Tags: android, listview, textview, contextmenu

First of all, my English is not so good.
I have a `ListView` [like this](http://lalit3686.blogspot.com.es/2012/06/today-i-am-going-to-show-how-to-deal.html) and another with `TextView`. 
My problem is that I want to put a `contextMenu` there, but I can't.  I lost a lot of time with this, and can't find solution.

I have used  `registerForContextMenu(listViewTotes)`, with `onCreateContextMenu` and `onContextItemSelected`.

Thanks!

Comment: What version of Android are you using?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you using OnItemLongClickListener(). Looks like, OnItemClickListener() didn't response for registerForContextMenu(arg0).

For using OnItemLongClickListener() example, the code is like this:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
    super.onCreate(icicle);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.my_list);
    adapter = new MyAdapter(this,getModel());
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    listView.setOnItemLongClickListener(new PlayListOnItemLongClickListener());
}

private class PlayListOnItemLongClickListener implements AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener {
    public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
        registerForContextMenu(arg0);

        return false;
    }
}

@Override
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.context_playlist_operation, menu);
    menu.setHeaderIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
    menu.setHeaderTitle("What do you want to do");
}
```

In /ListViewTest/res/menu/context_playlist_operation.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <group>
        <item
            android:id="@+id/context_playlist_remove_playlist"
            android:title="@string/app_name"
            />
    </group>
</menu>
```

Comment: This code does'nt work. I have a onlongclicklistener () on my adapter and it works now, but I put in a TextView...

Comment: Actually, I download the ListView code from blogspot.com that you are saying you have them. Then I add code like above, it works fine on my Android phone. Now, I add more code there, you may take a look at them. I'm sorry if the codes are not helping.